# DOMDocument PHP Memory Leak

Tags: php, memory-leaks, domdocument

Running PHP 5.3.6 under MAMP on MAC, the memory usage increases every x calls (between 3 and 8) until the script dies from memory exhaustion. How do I fix this?

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
while(true){
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.ebay.com/'));
 unset($dom);
 echo memory_get_peak_usage(true) . '<br>'; flush();
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Using `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);` suppresses error output but builds a continuous log of errors which is appended to on each loop. Either disable the internal logging and suppress PHP  warnings, or clear the internal log on each loop iteration like this:

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
while(true){
 $dom = new DOMDocument();
 $dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('ebay.html'));
 unset($dom);
 libxml_use_internal_errors(false);
 libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
 echo memory_get_peak_usage(true) . "\r\n"; flush();
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have searched high and low for this and never thought to look at the implications of using `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)`

Comment: I suspect this is also the answer to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8188729/domdocument-xpath-leaking-memory-during-long-command-line-process-any-way-to

Comment: Feel free to cross post in the other answer and/or link here and spread the love. @FrancisAvila Thanks, well spotted :)

Comment: +100 if I could! Dude, you're a life saver. All this time I thought it was DOMDocument fault and kept hacking around it, time to refactor. =)

Comment: Yeahhh!! I was blocked trying to know from where my memory leak came and you pointed in the right direction. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 3):

Based on [@Tak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8379947/89771) answer and @FrancisAvila comment, I found that this snippet works better for me:

```
while (true)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    if (libxml_use_internal_errors(true) === true) // previous setting was true?
    {
        libxml_clear_errors();
    }

    $dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('ebay.html'));
}

print_r(libxml_get_errors()); // errors from the last iteration are accessible
```

This has the added benefits of 1) not discarding the errors of the **last** parse if you ever need to access them via `libxml_get_errors()`, and 2) calling `libxml_clear_errors()` only when necessary, since `libxml_use_internal_errors()` returns the **previous** setting state.

Answer (score 1):

You can try forcing the garbage collector to run with [`gc_collect_cycles()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gc-collect-cycles.php), but otherwise you're out of luck. PHP doesn't expose much of anything to control its internal memory usage, let alone memory used by a plugin library.

Comment: Unfortunately the memory keeps getting consumed using `gc_enable()` at start of script and `gc_collect_cycles()` at the end of each loop returns 0.

Answer (score 0):

Testing your script locally produces the same result. Changing `file_get_contents()` to a local HTML file however produces a consistent memory usage. It could be that the output from ebay.com is changing every X calls.

Comment: Saving the eBay homepage to a local html file, and using that instead yields the same memory bloat for me. The included code is a simplification of my problem code - which is actually loading content from local caches.

Comment: Aha, found the solution - will post in separate answer