# PHP/DOMDocument: unset() does not release resources

Tags: php, memory-leaks, domdocument

I've got a variable `$dom` that contains an instance of PHP's DOMDocument. This variable is being set and unset within a loop.

`unset($dom)` will not release memory, though: `memory_get_usage(false)` reports that only 700B of about 10MB got released. `memory_get_usage(true)` reports the exact same amount of memory usage before and after `unset()`.

I tried the following:

- I checked that the reference count of $dom is exactly one immediately before the call to `unset()`: `xdebug_debug_zval('dom')` reports: dom: (refcount=1, is_ref=0)=class DOMDocument {  }.
- I tried the solution proposed in [DOMDocument PHP Memory Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379829/domdocument-php-memory-leak) but this was to no avail.
- I tried `gc_enable()` + `gc_collect_cycles()`. But this did not help either.
- I tried calling `$dom->__destruct()` before `unset()` but this will result in an error as DOMDocument apparently does not have a destructor.
- I recursively removed all nodes in the DOM before I unset the variable. It did not make the least difference.
- I tried setting the variable to null before re-using it: `$dom = null`

Now I'm out of ideas... Anybody got a suggestion what else I could try to debug or solve this problem?

Edit:

- php -v reports 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2 with Suhosin-Patch (cli)
- The source code can be seen here: https://github.com/jerico-dev/ojs/blob/dev/plugins/generic/lucene/classes/SolrWebService.inc.php#L256
- The output of the first few iterations is:

  ```
  before object creation: 19292296
  after object creation: 29849832
  before unset: 30055232
  after unset: 30054448
  before object creation: 29849592
  after object creation: 39858840
  before unset: 40079920
  after unset: 40079136
  before object creation: 39858272
  after object creation: 49923216
  before unset: 50136448
  after unset: 50135664
  ```

Comment: Hi.. I'm facing the same issue.. Did you find any workaround for it?

Comment: Sorry I don't remember any more. I remember that I didn't find a proper solution and somehow worked around it.

Comment: Does it have something to do with memory leak? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8379829/domdocument-php-memory-leak

Comment: @JuniorMayhé: As you can see in my original post, I had already linked to that question. That wasn't the problem in my case. I seem to remember that it had something to do with a memory leak in the mysql driver (cached SQL statements) but I don't remember how that was triggered through the usage of a DOM model.

Answer (score 1):

This should release the memory store in $dom.

```
$dom = null;
```

Comment: It "should"? have you tested it?

Comment: Did you just downvote because of my wording? Yes, it will rewrite the memory.

Comment: I did not downvote your answer. It as no upvotes and no downvotes. (You can check your reputation history to determine that).

Comment: Sorry, I had already tried that. I just forgot it in my list. You can see it in the source code, too. It doesn't work.

Comment: @Truth ah okay. I just saw a random downvote around the same time. My apologies!

Comment: @jerico I see that you are using unset() in your source, but I don't see you setting $articleDoc = null and $articleXML = null at the end of the loop.

Comment: It's happening in line 274. I've checked that the statement is actually being called. I even tried calling $dom=null immediately before unset.

Comment: Try calling $articleDoc = null; on line 296, and $articleXML = null on line 297. Line 274 is too early in the loop. Your memory output won't reflect the null rewrite on those two variables in its current form.