# DOMDocument loadHTML doesn't work properly on a server

Tags: php, dom

I run the code first on MAMP and it worked very well. But when I tried to run the code on another server, I got a lot of warnings like:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : head in Entity,
>   line: 3349 in /cgihome/zhang1/html/cgi-bin/getPrice.php on line 17 
>   Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseStartTag: misplaced tag in
>   Entity, line: 3350 in /cgihome/zhang1/html/cgi-bin/getPrice.php on
>   line 17  Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Tag header invalid in
>   Entity, line: 3517 in /cgihome/zhang1/html/cgi-bin/getPrice.php on
>   line 17

The codes are following:

```
<?php
 $amazon = file_get_contents('http://www.amazon.com/blablabla');
 $doc = new DOMdocument();
 $doc->loadHTML($amazon);
 $doc->saveHTML();
 $price = $doc -> getElementById('actualPriceValue')->textContent;
 $ASIN = $doc -> getElementById('ASIN')->getAttribute('value');
?>
```

Anyone knows what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 137, accepted):

To disable the warning, you can use

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
```

This works for me, [Manual](http://de.php.net/manual/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php), read on:

---

**Background:** You are loading invalid HTML. Invalid HTML is quite common, [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://de.php.net/DOMDocument.loadHTML) corrects most of the problems, but gives warnings by default.

With [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://de.php.net/manual/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) you can control that behavior. Set it before loading the document:

```
$previously = libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($amazon);
```

Then after loading you can deal with the errors (if you want/need to):

```
/* @var LibXMLError[] $xmlErrors */
$xmlErrors = libxml_get_errors();
```

And finally clear them (as they will add up) and restore the previous setting if applicable:

```
unset($xmlErrors);
libxml_clear_errors();
libxml_use_internal_errors($previously);
```

---

**References**

- [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://de.php.net/manual/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) Disable libxml errors and allow user to fetch error information as needed
- [`libxml_clear_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-clear-errors.php)  Clear libxml error buffer
- [`libxml_get_errors`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php) Retrieve array of errors
- [`LibXMLError`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.libxmlerror.php) The libXMLError class
- [Stackoverflow answer to *DOMDocument PHP Memory Leak*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8379947/367456) (by [Tak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/794713/tak); Dec 2011)

Comment: Also do not forget to visit the manual page for a function that creates some errors in the future. You often find useful notes and usage infos there. Also there are user-comments. See [`DOMDocument::loadHTML`](http://de.php.net/DOMDocument.loadHTML)

Comment: @user1577801: If this answer solved your problem, consider upvoting and accepting it, by clicking on the large green tick mark under the answer's score.

Answer (score 6):

This **problem** is related to non **xHTML** code

As **DOMdocument**() can only process **clean XHTML** you need to clean up your code

Php have an extension that does the job pretty well. Called Tidy 
[php.net/book.tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php)

It might be tricky as you may need to *enable* it in your **php.ini**

Then

```
$tidy_config = array( 
                     'clean' => true, 
                     'output-xhtml' => true, 
                     'show-body-only' => true, 
                     'wrap' => 0, 

                     ); 

$tidy = tidy_parse_string( $html, $tidy_config, 'UTF8'); 
$tidy->cleanRepair(); 
$doc = new DOMdocument();
$doc->loadHTML( (string) $tidy);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can surpress the warning like this:

```
@$doc->loadHTML($amazon);
```