# Unexpected end tag p in Entity in DOMDocument::loadHTML() error

Tags: php, compiler-errors, domdocument

Why do I get warning for this code?

```
$content ='<p>
 <a href="http://www.we.com/1000">text </a>
 text 
 <a href="http://www.we.com/2345">text </a>
  text 
</p>

<p>text</p>

<p>
  <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" dir="rtl"> 
      <tbody> 
          <tr> 
              <td>text </td> 
              <td>text </td> 
              <td>text </td> 
          </tr> 
          <tr> 
              <td>text </td> 
              <td>text </td> 
              <td>text </td> 
          </tr> 
      </tbody> 
  </table>
</p>';

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML($content);
```

The warning is:

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : p in Entity,
>   line: 25 in
>   /home/admin/domains/we.com/public_html/refresh/lib/core.php on
>   line 2213 <p> <a href="http://www.we.com/1000">text </a> text <a
>   href="http://www.we.com/2345">text </a> text </p> <p>text</p> <p>
>   </p><table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"
>   dir="rtl"><tbody><tr><td>text </td> <td>text </td> <td>text </td>
>   </tr><tr><td>text </td> <td>text </td> <td>text </td>
>   </tr></tbody></table>

Comment: Improve code formatting, grammar, escape html.

Answer (score 21):

Add **@** to suppress the warning as follows

```
@$doc->loadHTML($content);
```

This is because most of HTML objects are not perfectly formatted or even elements like "p" are automatically closed

Comment: Great thanks, I took the @ out from a snippet I got elsewhere thinking it was a typo! lol

Answer (score 6):

The end tag for paragraphs is optional. A table may not appear within a paragraph. The table start tag implicitly ends that paragraph. The next paragraph end tag has no open paragraph to close.

See "Tag omission in text/html" in [the spec for p](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element).

Comment: To disable the warning, use `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`, more here https://stackoverflow.com/a/11819635/1066234